# C program to print you are eligible if you are above 16 years old when entering birth year only, using functions get_input and validate_input

Tags: c, function

C program to print you are eligible if you are above 16 years old when entering birth year only, using functions get_input and validate_input. However, I am getting the same message saying "Sorry, you are not eligible" even if the age is more than 16. Please let me know where I am making the mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get_input(int x)
{
    printf("Enter your birth year:");
    scanf("%d", &x);
}

int validate_input(int y)
{
    int year;
    get_input(year);
    {
        if (y > 0){
            if ((2021 - y) >= 16){
                printf("You are eligible for the job!\n");}}
        else{
            printf("Sorry, you are not eligible for the job!\n");}
    }
}

int main()
{
    int birth_year;
    validate_input(birth_year);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are misunderstanding how you pass information back from a function call. This is covered in every textbook.

Comment: Also, `year` or `y`?

Comment: The reporting logic is faulty too. For an entry of say `2006` (if that part were corrected) so age 15, the program is silent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn how to call a function, use a variable as function parameters and how a function returns a value. As it seems from your code that you are trying to develop your skills I am just trying to help you with exact solution. I hope that you understand the code well at first and try to implement all by yourself from the beginning.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_input()
{
    int x;
    printf("Enter your birth year:");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    return x;
}

void validate_input(int y)
{    
    if ((2021 - y) >= 16){
        printf("You are eligible for the job!\n");}
    else{
        printf("Sorry, you are not eligible for the job!\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int birth_year, y;
    y= get_input();
    validate_input(y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am new and trying to learn. I learned how to use two functions but since it is three I got confused. I learnt how to do this now.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to declare a variable `birth_year` and pass that into `get_input()`. You haven't assigned it a value, so the number passed to the function is _undefined_. Its only purpose is to provide a variable so that `scanf()` has a valid address to write to. But that would be more easily accomplished by declaring a _local variable_ within `get_input()`.

Comment: Careful when you call others newbie and then suggest that this is a decent solution :) many errors like Tim points out and redundant checks on something that can't possibly be negative, poor variable initialization etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your approach, that I can see.

```
void get_input(int x)
{
    printf("Enter your birth year:");
    scanf("%d", &x);
}
```

This function takes an integer as a parameter, and overwrites the value passed in with the value entered by the user. That doesn't achieve anything, because the value is then discarded. It would be better to *return* an integer from the input function:

```
int get_input()
{
    int x;
    printf("Enter your birth year:");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    return x;
}
```

Second, we can simplify `validate_input()` greatly, and get it to return valuable information:

```
bool validate_input(int year)
{
    return ((2021 - year) >= 16);
}
```

Finally, the reporting or handling of the result is best placed in main. (I say this because it's useful to separate out the logic, and the input, from the output.)

```
int main()
{
    int year = get_input();

    if(validate_input(year))
    {
        printf("You are eligible for the job!\n");}
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Sorry, you are not eligible for the job!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, there's a problem with your fundamental approach. Someone's age depends not only upon their birth year, but whether they have had their birthday *this year*.

Comment: I think you did not consider the case that value of the year might be negative. Good explanation though.

Comment: I don't think it matters. If the question was asking whether the user was over 3000 years old, the same logic would work. Looking at it another way, if the user was immortal and born in 55BCE, they would be over 16 years of age. The logic as shown in the original question would say that they were not.

Comment: Oh! I thought we are considering year cant be negative.

Comment: That's a fair point. Often, negative numbers signify invalid input and they should be handled accordingly. But I think that when talking about years, negative isn't automatically invalid.

Answer (score -1):

in the below function

```
   int main()
{
    int birth_year;
    validate_input(birth_year);
    return 0;
}
```

**birth_year** is taking a garbage value so take input here that's why it is giving wrong input.

Also, in this

```
int validate_input(int y)
{
    int year;
    get_input(year);
```

**year** is taking garbage value , either assign some value to it or take input.